# Scroll text automatically with Image back ground

Tags: android, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I am implementing one small application in Android.In that i am planing to scroll text **AUTOMATICALLY**.

> I want to scroll horizontally like **credits in movie** and scroll vertically like **Head lines scrolling in TV News**

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

- For horizontal scrolling you can [refer this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16371310/2345913) which uses
  `TranslateAnimation` to serve the purpose.
- For vertical scrolling you can [refer this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4612082/2345913)..

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal scrolling try **android:marquee** property of textView.

Answer (score 0):

Textview can have horizontally scrolling text in this way:
**android:marquee**

and

in your code do this:

**textView.setSelected(true);**

very simple.. Hope it helps you