# Continuously scroll EditText horizontally

Tags: android

For an app I'm creating, I have a few fields which can not be made bigger due to the limited space. For that reason, I would like the fields to scroll continuously. This is a bit like sometimes found in car radios where for example the RDS information scrolls. Is this possible using Android? I've already tried it using the `Scroller` and `MovementMethod`:

```
myEditText.setScroller(new Scroller(this)); 
myEditText.setMaxLines(1); 
myEditText.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
myEditText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

However, this doesn't do what I want it to do. This is my EditText:

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/pedigreeLineAEditText"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/line_height"
 android:clickable="false"
 android:cursorVisible="false"
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
 android:inputType="none"
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
```

Comment: By scrolling you mean animation which moves from left to right... RIGHT??  Then, check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16371310/2345913) , this will help

Comment: @CRUSADER thank you, that works. Now I only have to modify the code to not scroll over the whole screen, but only over a part, but I think I will succeed in that.

Comment: Check this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working/13246560#13246560

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be an EditText?  if not you can try something like this

```
  <TextView
android:text="START | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | END"
android:id="@+id/MarqueeText" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee" 
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
android:paddingRight="15dip" 
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
android:freezesText="true">
```

I don't think this will work with an Edit text in the same way but maybe this will work for you. This Code was from another answer that can be seen here

[TextView Marquee not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working)

Comment: This is not what I mean, I mean something like a ticker.

Comment: Then You want something like a marquee. Please see my Edit