# Marquee is not working with onGlobalLayoutListener

Tags: android

I am using TextView marquee which is running perfectly-

```
 final TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

    tv.setLayoutParams(paramsSong);

    tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    tv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    tv.setFreezesText(true);
    tv.setSingleLine(true);
    tv.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
    tv.setSelected(true);
    tv.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    rl.addView(tv);

    iv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                 //if I do nothing inside it marquee works..

                 //and if I add any TextView or any component then marquee does not work.

    }

});
```

> if I do nothing inside GlobalLayout then marquee works.. and if I add any
>   TextView or any component then marquee does not work.

I also tried by giving focus and setSelected inside GlobalLayout then also it is not working.

what is happening?

Comment: @CRUSADER its a imageview

Comment: [Refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16371310/2345913) .. It adds animation to text of textView , and it works for both long and short text, and for all api level...