# How make rss ticker in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, rss, news-ticker

how make android application rss ticker, 
i learn rss reader in http://www.itcuties.com/android/rss-reader-multicategory-reader-tab-layout-example/  ,but i want make rss ticker (running text)

[image: rss new ticker]

this is code from web http://www.itcuties.com/android/rss-reader-multicategory-reader-tab-layout-example/

```
public class RssTabsActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // First, set the content view
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rss_tabs);

    // Then get the TabHost
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Art tab
    Intent artIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
    // Set Art category RSS URL
    artIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture?format=xml");

    // The name of the art tab taken from the String resources
    String artTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_art);
    TabSpec artTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(artTabName)
                                .setIndicator(artTabName, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_art))
                                .setContent(artIntent);
    // Add art tab to the TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(artTabSpec);


    // Tech tab
    Intent techIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
    // Set Tech category RSS URL
    techIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologyNews?format=xml");

    // Tech tab name taken from the string resources
    String techTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_tech);
    TabSpec techTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(techTabName)
                                 .setIndicator(techTabName, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_tech))
                                 .setContent(techIntent);
    // Add tech tab to the TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(techTabSpec);


    // Sports tab
    Intent sportsIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
    // Set Sports category RSS URL
    sportsIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/sportsNews?format=xml");

    // Sports tab name - string resources
    String sportsTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_sports);
    TabSpec sportsTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(sportsTabName)
                                   .setIndicator(sportsTabName, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_sports))
                                   .setContent(sportsIntent);
    // Add sports tab to the TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(sportsTabSpec);


    // Set current tab to Technology
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
}
```

}

please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16371310/2345913

Comment: how about with RSS ticker  , please help ?