# How to horizontally scroll textview automatically with any text length?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, textview

I want to make my textview automatically scrollable even if there is not so much text to fit into the screen. Also I didn't found any library which can scroll textview horizontally, only vertically.

I created my textview and here is my xml code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/ticker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My text"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
```

In my activity I use:

```
TextView ticker = findViewById(R.id.ticker);
ticker.setSelected(true);
```

The main thing is that text scrolls if text length is more that can fit screen but I need to make scrolling with any text. Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

If `TextView` does not fill width the only thing is to call this method and pass `TextView` to it.

```
    fun addMarquee(textView: TextView) {
    textView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val pixels = textView.measuredWidth - 1
            val params = textView.layoutParams
            params.width = pixels
            textView.layoutParams = params
            textView.isSelected = true
            textView.ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE
            textView.isSingleLine = true
            textView.marqueeRepeatLimit = -1
            textView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
    })
}
```

**NOTE:** this method only work when textView width is `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to measure screen weight and put animation like a marquee.
Please refer to below link for the solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16371310/9121785

Answer (score 0):

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="This is an Example of Horizontal TextView Scrolling This is an Example of Horizontal TextView Scrolling This is an Example of Horizontal TextView Scrolling"/></HorizontalScrollView>
```

above code will help you to make a textview scollable